# Subscribe to a specific list of form fields and access all their values when 1 changes

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an Angular application using ngrx and have a group of form fields. I need to subscribe to all of them so when they change I can perform an action. I need to know the errors of all the field at that particular moment in time.

// Subscribe to status changes in each field in the list

```
for (const field of this.fields) {
    this.form.controls[field.id].statusChanges
         .subscribe((status) => {
              // Accessing field.id from here seems to work but I don't understand why
              const thisFieldErrors = this.form.controls[field.id].errors;
              // Other fields' errors??
         });

}
```

I have thought of using withLatestFrom but I have no idea how to pass the list of subscriptions for the status of each field.

Comment: Can you provide how you created your `fromgroup`?
The answer will depend on how you create the FormGroup

Comment: Hi @Nico, I am using the Angular Form Builder. this.formBuilder.group(fields);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to loop through the form controls...

```
for (const field of this.fields) {
    this.form.controls[field.id].statusChanges
        .subscribe((status) => {    
            for (const fieldKey in this.form.controls) {
                if (this.form.controls.hasOwnProperty(fieldKey)) {
                    console.log(this.form.controls[fieldKey].errors);
                }
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for but this doesn't sound good solution to me , looks more like patch.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is :

```
this.form.valueChanges // <---- get fires when any field inside your form is changed
```

Comment: This is not really what I needed. I wanted to listen only for changes in the status of 1 particular field, and at that point get the value of all the controls in the form. This will notify the component every time any control value changes which is not what I was after. Thanks for your help anyway.